# HTML form field labels being set to 100% width on MS-Edge without instruction?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, forms

So I've been messing around with a form in a project I'm working on - and have discovered that on Microsoft Edge, the top border of the label on my form fields disappears (I assume the label is being set to `width: 100%;` and covering it up) and so far I can not recreate this in any other browser *or* figure out where the CSS that's doing this is.

Below is a code snippet and a link to the CodePen as well (so you can see it full-screen on Edge).

Image: [Form input comparison: Chrome Vs. Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v88LE.png)

CodePen: https://codepen.io/B-Lovegrove/pen/NadBVe

*Note: For best results, use full-screen on code snippet*

```css
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #363740 url("../media/bg.jpg") repeat scroll;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

a {
    color: #4b8ddb;
    text-decoration: none;
}

table.top_pattern {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.top_pattern tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0;
    width: 14%;
    height: 5px;
}

table.top_pattern tbody tr td.tc_1 {
    background: #7c8bc5;
}

table.top_pattern tbody tr td.tc_2 {
    background: #799c0c;
}

table.top_pattern tbody tr td.tc_3 {
    background: #2e4795;
}

.radio {
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.radio label {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]+.radio-label:before {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: .8em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #415086;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: white;
    content: '';
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:checked+.radio-label:before {
    background-color: #4b8ddb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:focus+.radio-label:before {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #4b8ddb;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]+.radio-label:empty:before {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.Important {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    background: rgba(139, 168, 46, 0.81);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

h1.Important {
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    background: rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.7);
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 2.1em;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

p,
ul {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

ul {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.Container {
    padding-bottom: 2.8em;
}

.Container .Content {
    margin: 1.7em 3em 0em 3em;
    padding: 1.5em;
    border: 1px solid #45464f;
    background: #363740;
}

.StaticForm {
    padding: 2em 1em 1em 1em;
    min-height: 70px;
    width: calc(100% - 32px);
    border: 1px solid #45464f;
    background: #2f3038;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.StaticForm .FormField {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #45464f;
}

.StaticForm .FormField:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.StaticForm .FormField>label:first-child {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -28px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    background: #2f3038;
    color: #4b8ddb;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm .FormField input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    border: none;
    background: #2f3038;
    color: #adadad;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm .FormField input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    border: none;
    background: #2f3038;
    color: #adadad;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm .FormField input::placeholder {
    border: none;
    background: #2f3038;
    color: #adadad;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Split {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    min-height: 41px;
    width: calc(50% - 27px);
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Split button {
    min-height: 41px;
    background-color: #4b8ddb;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Split button:hover {
    background-color: #3680d7;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Split:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Full {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 18px);
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Red,
.StaticForm .FormField.Blue {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border: none;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Red button,
.StaticForm .FormField.Blue button {
    min-height: 61px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b22c2c;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ce3939;
    color: white;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Red button:hover,
.StaticForm .FormField.Blue button:hover {
    background: #c23030;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Blue button {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #374d94;
    background: #415bae;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Blue button:hover {
    background: #3a519b;
}

.StaticForm input,
.StaticForm textarea,
.StaticForm button,
.StaticForm select {
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: #2f3038;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    resize: none;
}

.StaticForm .FormSubmit input,
.StaticForm .FormSubmit button,
.StaticForm .FormSubmit select {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #1b3669;
    background: #415bae;
    color: white;
}

.StaticForm .FormSubmit input:hover,
.StaticForm .FormSubmit button:hover,
.StaticForm .FormSubmit select:hover {
    background: #3a519b;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Accounts Container">
    <div class="Content">
        <form id="TeacherForm" class="StaticForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
            <ul>
                <li class="FormField Split">
                    <label for="teacher_code">Teacher code</label>
                    <input id="TeacherCode" type="text" name="teacher_code" maxlength="4" placeholder="Type teachers code" autofocus>
                </li>
                <li class="FormField Split">
                    <label for="name">Teacher name</label>
                    <input id="TeacherName" type="text" name="name" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers name">
                </li>
                <li class="FormField Split">
                    <label for="email">Teacher email</label>
                    <input id="TeacherEmail" type="email" name="email" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers email">
                </li>
                <li class="FormField Split">
                    <label for="password">Teacher password</label>
                    <input id="TeacherPassword" onfocus="RunOnce();" type="text" name="password" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers password">
                </li>
                <li class="FormField Split">
                    <label for="department_id">Teacher department</label>
                    <input id="TeacherDepartment" type="text" name="department_id" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers department">
                </li>
                <li class="FormField Split">
                    <label>Teacher subject</label>
                    <input id="TeacherSubject" type="text" name="subject_id" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers subject">
                </li>
                <li class="FormField Full">
                    <label for="elevation">Teacher elevation</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input id="teacher" class="TeacherElevation" name="elevation" type="radio" value=0 checked>
                        <label for="teacher" class="radio-label">Teacher</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input id="tic" class="TeacherElevation" name="elevation" type="radio" value=1>
                        <label for="tic" class="radio-label">Teacher in charge</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input id="hol" class="TeacherElevation" name="elevation" type="radio" value=2>
                        <label for="hol" class="radio-label">Head of learning</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input id="sysadmin" class="TeacherElevation" name="elevation" type="radio" value=3>
                        <label for="sysadmin" class="radio-label">Systems admin</label>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="FormSubmit">
                    <button id="TeacherSubmit">Register teacher</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #363740 url("../media/bg.jpg") repeat scroll;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #4b8ddb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

table.top_pattern {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.top_pattern tbody tr td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0;
  width: 14%;
  height: 5px;
}

table.top_pattern tbody tr td.tc_1 {
  background: #7c8bc5;
}

table.top_pattern tbody tr td.tc_2 {
  background: #799c0c;
}

table.top_pattern tbody tr td.tc_3 {
  background: #2e4795;
}

.radio {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

.radio label {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.radio input[type="radio"] + .radio-label:before {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .8em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #415086;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
  content: '';
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-label:before {
  background-color: #4b8ddb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:focus + .radio-label:before {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #4b8ddb;
}

.radio input[type="radio"] + .radio-label:empty:before {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.Important {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  background: rgba(139, 168, 46, 0.81);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

h1.Important {
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  background: rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.7);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2.1em;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

p, ul {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

ul {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.Container {
  padding-bottom: 2.8em;
}

.Container .Content {
  margin: 1.7em 3em 0em 3em;
  padding: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid #45464f;
  background: #363740;
}

.StaticForm {
  padding: 2em 1em 1em 1em;
  min-height: 70px;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  border: 1px solid #45464f;
  background: #2f3038;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.StaticForm .FormField {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #45464f;
}

.StaticForm .FormField:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.StaticForm .FormField > label:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -28px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
   width:-ms-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  background: #2f3038;
  color: #4b8ddb;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm .FormField input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  border: none;
  background: #2f3038;
  color: #adadad;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm .FormField input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  border: none;
  background: #2f3038;
  color: #adadad;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm .FormField input::placeholder {
  border: none;
  background: #2f3038;
  color: #adadad;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Split {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  min-height: 41px;
  width: calc(50% - 27px);
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Split button {
  min-height: 41px;
  background-color: #4b8ddb;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Split button:hover {
  background-color: #3680d7;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Split:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Full {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 18px);
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Red, .StaticForm .FormField.Blue {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Red button, .StaticForm .FormField.Blue button {
  min-height: 61px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #b22c2c;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ce3939;
  color: white;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Red button:hover,
.StaticForm .FormField.Blue button:hover {
  background: #c23030;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Blue button {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #374d94;
  background: #415bae;
}

.StaticForm .FormField.Blue button:hover {
  background: #3a519b;
}

.StaticForm input,
.StaticForm textarea,
.StaticForm button,
.StaticForm select {
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: #2f3038;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  resize: none;
}

.StaticForm .FormSubmit input,
.StaticForm .FormSubmit button,
.StaticForm .FormSubmit select {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1b3669;
  background: #415bae;
  color: white;
}

.StaticForm .FormSubmit input:hover,
.StaticForm .FormSubmit button:hover,
.StaticForm .FormSubmit select:hover {
  background: #3a519b;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="Brandon Lovegrove" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Options Selection - demo</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./media/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/complete.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <table class="top_pattern">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tc_1"></td>
        <td class="tc_2"></td>
        <td class="tc_3"></td>
        <td class="tc_1"></td>
        <td class="tc_2"></td>
        <td class="tc_3"></td>
        <td class="tc_1"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="Canvas">
    <div class="Accounts Container">
      <div class="Content">
        <form id="TeacherForm" class="StaticForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
          <ul>
            <li class="FormField Split">
              <label for="teacher_code">Teacher code</label>
              <input id="TeacherCode" type="text" name="teacher_code" maxlength="4" placeholder="Type teachers code" autofocus>
            </li>
            <li class="FormField Split">
              <label for="name">Teacher name</label>
              <input id="TeacherName" type="text" name="name" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers name">
            </li>
            <li class="FormField Split">
              <label for="email" >Teacher email</label>
              <input id="TeacherEmail" type="email" name="email" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers email">
            </li>
            <li class="FormField Split">
              <label for="password">Teacher password</label>
              <input id="TeacherPassword" type="password" name="password" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers password">
            </li>
            <li class="FormField Split">
              <label for="department_id">Teacher department</label>
              <input id="TeacherDepartment" type="text" name="department_id" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers department">
            </li>
            <li class="FormField Split">
              <label>Teacher subject</label>
              <input id="TeacherSubject" type="text" name="subject_id" maxlength="255" placeholder="Type teachers subject">
            </li>
            <li class="FormField Full">
              <label for="elevation">Teacher elevation</label>
              <div class="radio">
                <input id="teacher" class="TeacherElevation" name="elevation" type="radio" value=0 checked>
                <label for="teacher" class="radio-label">Teacher</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <input id="tic" class="TeacherElevation" name="elevation" type="radio" value=1>
                <label for="tic" class="radio-label">Teacher in charge</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <input id="hol" class="TeacherElevation" name="elevation" type="radio" value=2>
                <label for="hol" class="radio-label">Head of learning</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <input id="sysadmin" class="TeacherElevation" name="elevation" type="radio" value=3>
                <label for="sysadmin" class="radio-label">Systems admin</label>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="FormSubmit">
              <button id="TeacherSubmit">Register teacher</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. Though what exactly did you change?